# IPython IPCluster different path for different nodes

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

I have two nodes that I'd like to run IPython.parallel engines on. One of them is a linux box, the other runs MacOSX. The directory names are slightly different on the different machines and I can't find a way to start SSHEngines on both machines at the same time. It works on each of them individually.

For the MacOSX machine, I set the engine_cmd to

```
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engine_cmd = ['/Users/rein/git/rebound/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'IPython.parallel.engine']
```

whereas for the Linux machine I use

```
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engine_cmd = ['/home/rein/git/rebound/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'IPython.parallel.engine']
```

How can I define on an engine_cmd on a per engine basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking the simplest thing to do is to configure the `PATH` settings on two platforms so that a you don't need to fully specify the path to the python executable in your `engine_cmd`.

If you want to spend a little more time developing, you could mess with `ipcluster_config.py` as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822310/using-ipcluster-to-connect-to-an-os-x-server-w-epd-from-linux) from @minrk.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. In the meantime I've added a feature that allows you to specify the engine to the development version of ipython. Should be shipped with the next major version. See https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/pull/10